# HTML5 video player ,How to control on progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, progress-bar

I search for solution in many questions but I didn't get answer, I have HTML5 video play :

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" width="100%" height="auto" controls id="player"
controls controlsList="nodownload" poster="{{asset('images/'.$course->id.'.png')}}"
onended="alert('it is worked')">
    <source src="{{asset('promos/'.$course->id.'.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{asset('promos/'.$course->id.'.m4v')}}" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

it works fine but I cant control in  progress bar ,I can't move video forward or backward ,How can I do that ?

### is anyone can help ?

Video Link

```
https://streamable.com/k3rved
```

Answer (score 0):

You HTML5 looks fine - the video below will allow moving forwards and backwards using the scroll bar as a working example to refer to:

```html
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" width="100%" height="auto" controls id="player"
controls controlsList="nodownload" poster="{{asset('images/'.$course->id.'.png')}}"
onended="alert('it is worked')">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If the issue is the lack of thumbnails when you hover over the progress bar, then these need to be generated separately on the server side and included in the video container (e.g. mp4) that you make available.

**Update**

The video link in the question above is not actually a link to a video, rather it is a link to a webpage.

This webpage does indeed contain a video, along with the videoJS player, when you inspect it, but you can't use the webpage link as the 'src' attribute in a HTML5 video.

Assuming you have permission to use the video, you can extract the src from the video at that webpage. This works in this case, at the time of writing anyway - sometimes videos in a webpage will have access restrictions or authentication requirements to prevent them being accessed from other sites.

Comment: thanks sir ,really I don't why it is not work ,I worked on local server ,I don't think it is from server

Comment: @SM_Berwari - if you can share an example video that you see the problem with it might be useful to check that also

Comment: I added video link

Comment: @SM_Berwari - added an update above, that link is actually to a web page rather than a video.

Comment: that link is just show the problem ,do you need mp4 file? I tried many files but same problem I have

Comment: @SM_Berwari - actually I was able to access the file and I was able to scroll the video back and forwards, although it was more 'jerky' than some examples. I tried in Chrome and Safari on a Mac and it worked on both.